# How to Click Link Being Covered by Another Element? Python 3.6 and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Having trouble figuring out how to click the Next button at the bottom of the table on this page:

https://www.zacks.com/stocks/industry-rank/reit-and-equity-trust-other-266/stocks-in-industry

This is what I've tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv, random, time
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


url = 'https://www.zacks.com/stocks/industry-rank/reit-and-equity-trust-other-266/stocks-in-industry'

    # Open Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Send Chrome to the URL
page = driver.get(url)

    # Wait for page to load a few seconds
timeDelay = random.randrange(4, 8)
time.sleep(timeDelay)

    # Try to click the darn button
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="industry_rank_table_next"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

...and

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="industry_rank_table_next"]')
element.send_keys("\n")
```

...found from other answers but not working for me. Simply using `.click()` does not work. I've also tried selecting the button using `css_selector`, `partial_link_text`, and `class_name` but still no success. I've ran into this on a few sites. Any ideas?

Comment: try `element.click()` ?

Comment: Even if button is covered by another element (I guess it is *Cookies warning* at the bottom of page) `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element) ` should still work. What is exception you got?

Comment: @Andersson It's interesting, the code clicks the link successfully, but then I get a "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' " error, so I'm going to just add a try/except option to handle the error. I'm going to update. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Next** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Next"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.paginate_button next#industry_rank_table_next"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='paginate_button next' and @id='industry_rank_table_next']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this, this helps a lot rather than using a sleep function.

Comment: @MattWilson But I expected this answer to solve you question as well. Can I get a status please?

Comment: Incase you are seeing _WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'_ that is due to version mismatch between _ChromeDriver_ and _Chrome Browser_

Answer (score 1):

if the element which you have to click have parent element then you can find parent by findElements method and after than you just need to pass the index of the element like 0 or  1 or so on.. and then you can perform click action on that

```
Want to click on third li from second ul:

   <ul id="select-123" style="width: 1180px; display: none;">
   <li class="" style="display:none;">
   <li class="">
   <li class="">
   <li class="">
   </ul>

   <ul id="select-123" style="width: 1180px; display: none;">
   <li class="" style="display:none;">
   <li class="">
   <li class="">
   <li class="">
   </ul>


Code I am trying is to select third li from second ul which does not work:

    driver.findElements(By.css(ul[id*='select-123'])).then(function(elems) {
    elems[2].then(function(lis) {
    driver.findElement(By.css("ul[id*='select-123'] li:nth-child(3)")).click();
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you don't wish to add additional wait(s) to your code and just click the button:

using javascript click:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='paginate_button next' and @id='industry_rank_table_next']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

I didn't notice this earlier, but

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="industry_rank_table_next"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

...works as it clicks the link successfully, but gives me a

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
```

...error after it clicks the link. So to get around this, I've just added a try/except to handle the error. ie:

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="industry_rank_table_next"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
except:
    pass
```

...which seems to work. Seems like such a stupid observation on my part, but thank you to everyone for your help. Hopefully something in here will help someone else in the future.